# Where can I find that jsFiddle demo button?

Tags: support

In a few answers I read a while ago (which I can no longer locate), someone had included a jsFiddle button for their demo link, and despite searching endlessly, I have not been able to find it again. This would be useful for making my questions and answers more readable, plus it looks kinda neat.

It was something like a jsFiddle version of this Dabblet one:
[image]

Comment: I don't think one exists. At least, not officially.

Comment: I know it's not official, but I have seen one around

Comment: That Dabblet button disrespects Dabblet.

Comment: Do we actually want to encourage this? They remind me of forum posts with overly fancy images to make headers.

Comment: @minitech I know, but best example I could find

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Go to Fiddle Button]

```
[![Go to Fiddle Button][2]][1]

  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/txsGw.png (Click here for the Fiddle)
```

(you don't get the underline on the main site)

Answer (score -4):

I sometimes use the `kbd` tag for this purpose. This has the advantage of not requiring you to upload or remember the URL of an image. [**<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>**](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)

```
[**<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>**](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)
```

Combine with `&rarr;` for an arrow as you had in your question. [**<kbd>JSFiddle →</kbd>**](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: No, that's [not what the kbd element is for](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-kbd-element).

Comment: @bjb568: Very true. I, [like others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1974/210346), abuse them anyway. For that matter, I abuse other tags, such as poor `sub` and `sup`, too, as suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/34361/210346). Not that it makes it any more valid.

Comment: I frequently go through Data Explorer queries and mass edit posts which abuse this formatting.

Comment: @animuson: Oops. I guess I’ll be seeing some edits from you soon, then.

Comment: It makes a nice button and keyboard representation is so rare that, heck, why not... Witch-hunting it seems abusive...